# Background Images incorrectly zoom in and not kept to proportion

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a whack a mole game. I want the mole's image to be a randomly generated picture from an array of png of friends.

Problem: when I choose the picture from an array, the size becomes disproportional and zooms in randomly. But when I choose only one image, it works fine.

My Result:
[image: My Result]

What I expect:
[image: Expected]

My HTML:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Whack A Chubs!</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src = "./app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Whack A Chubs <span class="score">0</span></h1>
  <button onClick="startGame()">Start!</button>
  
  <div class="game">
    <div class="hole hole1">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole2">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole3">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole4">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole5">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole6">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #ffc600;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.score {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 0 3rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.game {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hole {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hole:after {
  display: block;
  background: url(images/dirt.svg) bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height:70px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: -30px;
}
---------------------------
I WANT TO CHANGE THIS PART
-----------------------------

.mole {
  background: url(images/c5.png) bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}

.hole.up .mole {
  top: 0;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  background: #ffc600;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 400%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 47%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

My Javascript:

```
  const holes = document.querySelectorAll('.hole');
  const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('.score');
  const moles = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');
  let lastHole;
  let timeUp = false;
  let score = 0;
  let lastMole;



  function randomTime(min, max){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
  }

  function randomHole(holes) {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * holes.length);
    const hole = holes[idx];
    if (hole === lastHole) {
      console.log('Ah nah thats the same one bud');
      return randomHole(holes);
    }
    lastHole = hole;
    return hole;
  }

  function peep(){

    const time = randomTime(200, 1000);
    const hole = randomHole(holes);
    hole.classList.add('up'); 

-------------------------------------
THE JS I TRIED TO WRITE TO CHANGE THE PICTURE
------------------------------------------

    // const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);

    // moles.forEach(mole =>
    //   mole.style.background = `url(images/c${idx}.png) center center no-repeat`
    // );

    setTimeout(()=>{
      hole.classList.remove('up')
      if(!timeUp) peep();  
    }, time);
  }

  function startGame(){
    scoreBoard.textContent = 0;
    timeUp = false;
    score = 0;
    peep();
    setTimeout(() => timeUp = true, 10000)
  }

  function bonk(e){

    if(!e.isTrusted || e.target.parentElement === lastMole) return;
    lastMole = e.target.parentElement;
    this.classList.remove('up');
    score ++;
    scoreBoard.textContent = score;

  }

  moles.forEach(mole => mole.addEventListener('click', bonk));
```

`

I suspected that the pictures that I had may not be the same size. However, when I tried them individually in my css it works. I didn't change any stylings in my JS where I generate random images besides the image's url. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Thank you for reading. Please help. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Why when you position just one mole image do you have bottom center but when you are positioning your randomly chosen one you have center center?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AHaworth I meant to put bottom center. But I was tweaking it to see if anything changes, and it doesn't.